# Translate external xml

Tags: android, android-studio, translation, android-parser

I have a XML file inside the raw folder in portuguese that gives some quotes to a cardview. What I want to do now is have some translations to this XML file. I need to parse that XML so how can I create the translation for this and how I call it on code, so that my app knows what file should be used according to the OS idiom?

> EDIT

Short version of the xml file:

```
<tips>
    <tip>
        <tiptitle>Sabia que:</tiptitle>
        <tiptext>A Torre Eiffel fica 15 cm maior que seu tamanho original no verão.</tiptext>
        <tiptype>Tyoe</tiptype>
        <tipYear>2016</tipYear>
        <tipMonth>03</tipMonth>
        <tipDay>16</tipDay>
        <tipHour>11</tipHour>
        <tipMinute>24</tipMinute>
    </tip>
</tips>
```

Comment: you must add it manually !!
add a folder with the language you want and puting the appropriate translation

Comment: And how can my app know if the android's idiom is portuguese or english for example?

Comment: Why can't you use http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html ?

Comment: @Heisenberg I'm using it. But imagine if I have two XML files, one in portuguese and one in english, what's the one that I should parse? That's why I asked how can I know which file should be parsed. I found the answer tho. I just needed this `String deviceLocale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();` and an if `deviceLocale.equals("en")` for example.

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple languages, you can have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html). What you have to do basically is to store all your strings in different string resources. Each string resource is placed inside a values folder with a specif name (you must use the proper name for each language). For example:

```
 res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
```

At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device, so you don't have to worry about checking the language.

So you will have to write down your text from your xml file into a string resource (one for each language).

Comment: I want to translate the xml file in **raw folder**. As I mention in the question, I need to parse the file.